# WHERE ... IN with multiple columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I try to get some users which meet certain conditions:

```
SELECT * FROM users
WHERE lastname IN ('Pitt','Jolie','Costner') 
AND firstname IN ('Brad','Angelina','Kevin')
```

But this way, Kevin Jolie and Brad Costner will be shown, which is NOT what I need.

So I tried:

```
SELECT * FROM users
WHERE (lastname,firstname) IN ('Pitt','Brad'),('Jolie','Angelina'),('Costner','Kevin')
```

Which throws the error:

```
An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near ','.
```

Do you know a query that will yield my expected result?

Attn: *The two or more columns are not always varchar columns, they may be of any type.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would  use a query like this (but i'm using SQL-Server 2005, maybe there's something neater now):

```
SELECT * FROM users
WHERE 
    (firstname = 'Angelina' AND lastname = 'Jolie') 
OR
    (firstname = 'Brad' AND lastname = 'Pitt') 
OR
    (firstname = 'Kevin' AND lastname = 'Costner')
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this please.

```
SELECT * FROM users
WHERE lastname+firstname IN ('PittBrad','JolieAngelina','CostnerKevin')
```

**In case the columns have null then**

```
SELECT * FROM users
WHERE ISNULL(lastname,'')+ISNULL(firstname,'') IN ('PittBrad','JolieAngelina','CostnerKevin')
```

Comment: No. Wrong and inefficient.